# Flutter using StreamBuilder with setState updates

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm using a StreamBuilder inside a build method to retrieve user info from firestore and right after it is displayed with a Listview.builder.

Once i have retrieved the user info, i call another API with the user id's to retrieve some other info i would like to display in the list. This gives me a Future for each user, once the future has been "fulfilled" (inside Future.then()), then i save the data and call SetState(); to rebuild the list with the new data.

The problem is once setState() is called the Build method is rerun which gives me the users again, and this causes an endless loop of retrieving the users and the data from the second API.

This seems like a typical scenario but i don't know how to solve this with StreamBuilder. My previous solution retrieved the users in initState so it was not recalled endlessly.
Any tips?

"getOtherAPIData" loops the users retrieved and adds data "distance" to the list, and the list is sorted based on the user with the most/least distance.
Code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder<List<IsFriend>>(
    stream: viewModel.isFriendStream(),
    builder: (_, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        List<IsFriend> friends = snapshot.data;
        if (friends == null || friends.isEmpty) {
          return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Text("Friend list is empty :("),
              )
          );
        } else {
          userList = friends;
          getOtherAPIData();
          return getListview(userList);
        }
      }
      return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
      );
    }
  ),

..
..
void getOtherAPIData() async {
for (IsFriend friend  in userList) {
  await fitbitServ.getData(friend.user.uid).then((fitData) {
    setState(() {
      setDistanceOnUser(fitData.distanceKm, friend.user.uid);
      totalDistance += fitData.distanceKm;
      sortUsers(userDataList);
      userData[friend.user.uid] = fitData;
    });
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never call a method that starts loading data from within your `build` method. The normal flow I use is:

1. Start loading the data in the constructor of the widget.
2. Call `setState` when the data is available.
3. Render the data from the state in `build`.

Comment: So the solution is to not use StreamBuilder in cases like this? I don't see how i could use your approach in this scenario since the retrieval of my data is dependant on the data from the streamBuilder (which of course is inside build() )

Comment: Using a `StreamBuilder` is fine too, but you can't then start loading the data that it renders in its own `builder` body. Nesting builders is fine, but as soon as a builder triggers the loading of its own data in its `builder` method, you're triggering a loop as you see.